# StreamWritter UTF8 Encoding Error

Tags: c#, utf-8, wcf-rest

We are developing an android,wp &iOS  application using File Linking strategy of Xamarin.
We have written WCF REST Service to input/output as JSON format data.

In database class we have used ASCII format and it works fine, but we tried to change UTF8 format to support for multiple languages.  While changing we are getting error as "**The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request**" in **HttpWebResponse** line.

Please find the sample database function for sending data to WCF REST Service with UTF-8. Kindly suggest to resolve.

```
 public async Task<String> GetString<T>(T item, String ServiceAddress, String FunctionName, String[] Parameters, object[] ParameterValues) where T : BusinessLayer.Contracts.IBusinessEntity, new()
    {
        string ParameterString = string.Empty;
        try
        { 
            var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(ServiceAddress);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = GlobalVariables.glbtoken;
            if (Parameters.Length > 0)
                ParameterString = "{";
            for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Length; i++)
            {
                ParameterString = ParameterString + "\"" + Parameters[i] + "\":\"" + ParameterValues[i] + "\"" + ",";
            }
            if (Parameters.Length > 0)
            {
                ParameterString = ParameterString.Remove(ParameterString.Length - 1, 1);
                ParameterString += "}";
            }

            // var sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
             var sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            sw.Write(ParameterString); **//This string is not passed to server and shows null**
            sw.Close();
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse) // Here the line breaks and returned to catch with no parameters passed.
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();                
                    if (content != "")
                        OutputString = (string)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        return OutputString;
    }
```

Comment: When debugging what exception are you getting? What have you tried?

Comment: It shows "No input parameters passed to WCF Rest Service function" and "Bad request 400 error" returned.

Comment: The unicode byte order prefix might be your problem. Try using `new UTF8Encoding(false)` instead of `Encoding.UTF8`; that omits the prefix bytes.